# Change directory and executing external command in cmd - ERLANG

Tags: cmd, erlang

I am working on Erlang script that need to execute some command in cmd. I was trying to solve problem on this way, but I get nothing.

```
start() ->
    comparing(0000).

comparing(Num) ->
    file:set_cwd("F:\Documents\UPI\dump_rabbitmq\rabbitmq-dump-queue-v0.3-windows-amd64"),
    DirOut = os:cmd("dir"),
    io:format("DirOut=~p~n", [DirOut]),
    os:cmd('rabbitmq-dump-queue -uri="amqp://username:password@localhost:5672/" -queue=try -full -max-messages=5 -output-dir=E:\Programs\Erlang\erl8.3\usr'),
    NumMes = Num,
    io:format("NumMes=~p~n", [NumMes]),
    NameF = "msg-000",
    io:format("NameF=~p~n", [NameF]),
    FileName = concat(NameF, lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p", [NumMes]))),
    io:format("FileName=~p~n", [FileName]),
    File = filelib:is_regular(FileName),
    io:format("File=~p~n", [File]),
    ...
```

This is just a part of code where I have a problem. In line `file:set_cwd("F:\Documents\UPI\dump_rabbitmq\rabbitmq-dump-queue-v0.3-windows-amd64")` I want to change directory. 
In this two lines I check if directory is changed:

```
DirOut = os:cmd("dir"),
io:format("DirOut=~p~n", [DirOut])
```

And in line `os:cmd('rabbitmq-dump-queue -uri="amqp://username:password@localhost:5672/" -queue=try -full -max-messages=5 -output-dir=E:\Programs\Erlang\erl8.3\usr')` I want to execute command in cmd for dump messages from RabbitMQ server. I was trying to change directory with `os:cmd("cd F:\Documents\UPI\dump_rabbitmq\rabbitmq-dump-queue-v0.3-windows-amd64")`, but nothing happends. Any suggestion how to solve this problem?

**EDIT**

Problem is solved. It's neccesary to have two slashes in this line: `file:set_cwd("F:\\Documents\\UPI\\dump_rabbitmq\\rabbitmq-dump-queue-v0.3-windows-amd64")` Dogbert solved the problem in comments.

Comment: Try `file:set_cwd("F:\...")` instead of `os:cmd("cd F:\...")`.

Comment: I was try that in line `file:set_cwd("F:\Documents\UPI\dump_rabbitmq\rabbitmq-dump-queue-v0.3-windows-amd64")` but nothing happends. Also `os:cmd("cd F:\...")`, but still nothing.

Comment: Does the output of `os:cmd("dir")` not change when you change `os:cmd("cd ...")` to `file:set_cwd("...")`?

Comment: Output `os:cmd("dir")` is always the same. In any case is unchanged.

Comment: And when I execute command `os:cmd('rabbitmq-dump-queue -uri="amqp://username:password@localhost:5672/" -queue=try -full -max-messages=5 -output-dir=E:\Programs\Erlang\erl8.3\usr')` nothing happends. In normal way, I would have dump messages in `E:\Programs\Erlang\erl8.3\usr`

Comment: Can you try double escaping all the slashes? Otherwise Erlang interprets some as escape sequence and ignores others. `file:set_cwd("F:\\Documents\\UPI\\...")` etc in all strings/atoms/binaries. If that doesn't fix it, you'll probably have to wait for someone with Windows experience; I haven't used Windows in years.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot :) What a dumb problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems in the code:

1. You cannot change the working directory with `os:cmd("cd ...")`, you need to call `file:set_cwd/1`. `os:cmd("cd ...")` will only change the directory for the execution of that command, the change will not persist for future calls to `os:cmd/1`.
2. You need to escape the slashes, otherwise they're interpreted as escape sequence when it's a valid escape sequence, otherwise they're ignored.

   ```
   1> io:format("~s~n~s~n", ["C:\abc\nop", "C:\\abc\\nop"]).
   C:abc
   op
   C:\abc\nop
   ```

So, changing this:

```
os:cmd("cd F:\Documents\UPI\dump_rabbitmq\rabbitmq-dump-queue-v0.3-windows-amd64"),
```

to:

```
file:set_cwd("F:\\Documents\\UPI\\dump_rabbitmq\\rabbitmq-dump-queue-v0.3-windows-amd64"),
```

should fix your problem.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use forward slashes: `F:/Documents/UPI/dump_rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dump-queue-v0.3-windows-amd64`